# IIS Shared Configuration gMSA Credentials

Tags: iis, windows-server-2008-r2, iis-8

Im trying to use shared configuration for IIS Nodes in my environment, 
and i want to use Group managed Service Account Credentials to Achieve that.

 
 when i apply the credintial for the Application Pool As MyDomain\GmsaAccount$ it works well , However when i try to do the same in the shared configuration.

it shows an error message "Cannot Connect to the specified path, Make sure that the path and credentials are valid.

I have double checked the path and the gMSA user information and all is good, but somehow im not able to connect using any gMSA Account.

[image]

The IIS Version 8.5 on Windows Server 2012 R2 
The File Share Server is on Windows Server 2012 R2 and all on the same domain

Any Ideas ?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

For iis 8 on 2012 I had the same issue.

What I did was to leave the username and password fields blank.

It worked and a popup came up for the password.

Comment: thanks ,thats what i end up  doing , i left it empty, interesting that you got the popup , i will check it out